# Настройка WiFi для Windows 98 SE

Tags: windows, wifi

Есть старенький ПК с Windows 98 SE на борту, как мне на нём настроить WI-FI, есть также wi-fi адаптер usb tp-link 821 при подключении к пк пишет неизвестное устройство и пытается установить драва требуя вставить диск с виндовс в дисковод, но на диске с нет дров на оф.сайте тплинк тоже дрова только для 2000 ХР 7 8 ДЛЯ 98 НЕТ.

Вопрос, возможно ли вообще законектится через вай фай на Windows 98 ?

Comment: это не ноут а РС  озу 256 проц AMD K-6 233Mhz ( хочу попробовать поставить xubuntu 12.04 но не уверен она на таком проце заведется ? )

Comment: на такой машине с гарантией заведется Damn Small Linux, либо другой дистр, созданный для старых/маломощных систем (погуглите на эту тему).  Попробуйте найти драйвера, ориентируясь на pid/uid устройства: есть соответсвующие сайты.  В любом случае, необходимо Вам плотно поработать с поисковиками.

Answer (score 1):

Доброго дня!
Выхода два:
 1. Либо упроно стараемся найти дрова под 98-ю;
 2. Либо ставим ХРюшу.
Я предпочел бы установку ХР. Сообщите, плз, характеристики ноута (у меня ХР работал на P-III 500Mhz 320 MB оперативки на ноуте TP 600x).
3. Да, работа с Вай-Фай на 98-ой возможна, но нужны драйвера и программа управления от сторонних разработчиков (т.к. 98-я, насколько помню, не имеет приложений по управлению вай-фай).

Comment: Как вариант есть ещё Windows FLP (XP для устаревшиш компов). Это здесь: http://www.2admina.net/page/windows-dlja-staryh-kompjuterov-windows-flpСам устанавливал на подобной (см. ниже) конфигурации, и работает нормально. Современные версии прог там правда не устанавливаются, но всегда можно найти более старые.

Answer (score 0):

Приветсвую!Достаточно вариантов написали. Если чисто для интернета ноут нужен, то я бы воспользовался или Windows FLP, описанный выше, или Lubuntu, разновидность Linux.С вероятностью 98 процентов что для Windows 98 драйверов под вай-фай адптер нет.